# ggplot2 - two or more lines on y axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I need two or more lines of text on my y-axis title. However, the title is cut off if I have multiple lines. Anyway I can work around this?

`ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +geom_line()+labs(y=expression(paste("line 1 \nline2")))`

[image]

Comment: wouldn't just `ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +geom_line()+ ylab("line 1 \nline2")` work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play with `plot.margin` in `theme` to change the whitespace around your plot

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(y = expression(paste("line 1\nline2"))) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, "cm")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ylab`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line()+
  ylab(bquote("Mean Annual \nAir Temperature"~degree*"C")) +   
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, "cm"))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: That works! But I have another problem. My title involves temperature which needs (degree*C). Using ```ylab("temperature (degree*C)")``` does not recognize the degree function.
This is my original command
```labs(y=expression(paste("       Mean Annual \nAir Temperature " ( degree*C))))```. (degree*C) is outside of the quotations.